How to run the selected text/query within Azure Data Studio?
I am on macOS and have selected some text to execute in an ADS query editor:

The keyboard bindings show that CMD-F5 or F5 should run it:

However pressing either key [combination] does nothing. So then how can the currently selected text/query be run by a keyboard shortcut?

Just F5 should run your selected query. Ctrl/[Apple Icon]+F5 should run, but is for running the query your cursor is currently within.

@ThomA Neither do anything

Sounds like a specific Apple issue then, I'm afraid.

The default keybindings listed in the question do not work on macOS.  I have updated the keyboard shortcut settings to a different set of keys and it does work. In particular I am now using CTL-CMD-R
